Why is the camera not detected on MacBook M1?
Why is the camera not detected on MacBook M1? I am using macOS Sonoma.
I have tried permission access to see if I got any issue with it but permission is fine, when I turn on FaceTime or Zoom, the camera message I get is "No camera detected."
What are other ways I can try to check my camera reset on my own before I book a Genius bar appointment?

Test Safe Boot mode, and in a brand new user account. If it still doesn't work in both of those, then it's likely a hardware issue.

No green light is shown next to the camera when you start any app, correct?

Open System Information app
On the left is a section for Camera.
If you want remote assistance, open a support case with Apple on the web or app or by phone. They will let you know if you should use that app to send your configuration information to Apple.
The hardware detection by the OS should be easy to check. Then you can decide if you need a repair or its software (restart, safe mode, backup, erase install, etc…) once you are sure it’s not just OS permissions and privacy blocking the apps from seeing the camera that system information shows as connected, you would then need to check the connectors or get hardware repair for the display.
